# React modal have some issue while on running the project

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

I had tried to generate a Modal using the referral https://trendmicro-frontend.github.io/react-modal/#modalbody... But after installing the react modal I tried to run my code using the same code given in the above site. But some errors occurred like Uncaught ReferenceError: FromGroup is not defined, Uncaught ReferenceError: Label is not defined... I tried to copy the first example given on the site. What do I need to do resolve my issue?
Here is my code,

```
import Modal from '@trendmicro/react-modal';
import '@trendmicro/react-modal/dist/react-modal.css';
..........................

{flag &&
<Modal showOverlay={false}>
    <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title>
            Modal title
        </Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
        <FormGroup>
            <Label>Email address</Label>
            <Input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email"
            />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
            <Label>Password</Label>
            <Input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
            />
        </FormGroup>
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
        <Button>Cancel</Button>
        <Button btnStyle="primary">Save</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
}
```

Comment: Add your code what you have tried so far?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Yeah I updated my code

Comment: Do you find the solution yet. You need to install this package https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-form-control and import here in the code to work this code. Let me know if you are struggling yet.